Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0 with NDSolve
I am trying to use NDSolve to compute the solutions for a master equation of a 6x6 density matrix, equivalent to 21 first order coupled ODEs.
The equations are computed as follows
(*Parameters*)
\[HBar] = UnitConvert[Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"]];
h = UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"]];
c = UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]];
Subscript[\[Epsilon], 0] = UnitConvert[Quantity["ElectricConstant"]];

\[CapitalGamma] = Quantity[2 \[Pi]*180.6447, "Kilohertz"];
ReducedMatrixElement = Quantity[4.55426*10^-30, ("Amperes" "Meters")/("Hertz")]
\[CapitalDelta] = Quantity[2.99315*10^10, "Hertz"]
Subscript[\[CapitalIota], OP] = 
  Quantity[1, "Watts"/("Centimeters")^2];

\[CapitalOmega][q_] := 
 UnitConvert[
  Piecewise[{{ReducedMatrixElement/\[HBar]*
      Sqrt[(2*Subscript[\[CapitalIota], OP])/(Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
           0]*c)], q == -1}, {0*ReducedMatrixElement/\[HBar]*
      Sqrt[(2*Subscript[\[CapitalIota], OP])/(Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
           0]*c)], True}}], "Kilohertz"]

Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFg_, mFe_, q_] := -2*
   ClebschGordan[{3/2, mFe}, {1, q}, {1/2, mFg}]*
   SixJSymbol[{1, 0, 1}, {1/2, 3/2, 1/2}]*\[CapitalOmega][q];
\[Xi][mFa_, mFb_, q_] := 
 ClebschGordan[{1/2, mFa}, {1, q}, {3/2, mFa + q}]*
  ClebschGordan[{1/2, mFb}, {1, q}, {3/2, mFb + q}]

(*Density Matrix*)
Subscript[\[Rho], M] = Array[\[Rho], {6, 6}] // MatrixForm

(*Equations*)
Clear[equations];
equations := {};
Quiet[
  For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, j = 1;
   While[j <= i,
    (* Equations for populations and coherences of the Ground State \
Manifold *)
    If[i <= 2 && j <= 2,
     mFi = i - 3/2;
     mFj = j - 3/2;
     AppendTo[
      equations, \[Rho][i, j]'[
        t] == \[CapitalGamma]*
         Sum[\[Rho][3 + i + q, 3 + j + q][t]*\[Xi][mFi, mFj, 
            q], {q, -1, 1}] -
        I/2*
         Sum[+Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFi, mFa, 
              mFi - mFa]*\[Rho][mFa + 9/2, j][t] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFj, mFb, mFj - mFb]*
            Conjugate[\[Rho][mFb + 9/2, i][t]], {mFa, -(3/2), 3/
           2}, {mFb, -(3/2), 3/2}]
      ]];
    (* Equations for populations and coherences of the Excited State \
Manifold *)
    If[i >= 3 && j >= 3,
     mFi = i - 9/2;
     mFj = j - 9/2;
     AppendTo[equations, 
      \[Rho][i, j]'[t] == -\[CapitalGamma]*\[Rho][i, j][t] - 
        I/2* Sum[
          Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFa, mFi, mFa - mFi]*
            Conjugate[\[Rho][j, mFa + 3/2][t] ] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFb, mFj, 
             mFb - mFj]*\[Rho][i, mFb + 3/2][t], {mFa, -(1/2), 1/
           2}, {mFb, -(1/2), 1/2}]]];
    (* Equations for mixed ground-excited states coherences *)
    If[i >= 3 && j < 3,
     mFi = i - 9/2;
     mFj = j - 3/2;
      AppendTo[equations,
      \[Rho][i, j]'[
        t] == (-(\[CapitalGamma]/2) + I*\[CapitalDelta])*\[Rho][i, j][
          t] - I/2*
         Sum[Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFa, mFi, 
             mFa - mFi]*\[Rho][mFa + 3/2, j][t] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFj, mFb, 
             mFj - mFb]*\[Rho][i, mFb + 9/2][t], {mFa, j - 3/2, 1/
           2}, {mFb, -(3/2), i - 9/2}] - 
        I/2*Sum[Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFa, mFi, mFa - mFi]*
            Conjugate[\[Rho][j, mFa + 3/2][t]] - 
           Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], H][mFj, mFb, mFj - mFb]*
            Conjugate[\[Rho][mFb + 9/2, i][t]], {mFa, -(1/2), 
           j - 3/2 - 1}, {mFb, i - 9/2 + 1, 3/2}]]];
    j++
    ]]];
(* Initial Conditions *)
AppendTo[equations, \[Rho][1, 1][0] == 1];
For[i = 2, i <= 6, i++, j = 1; 
  While[j <= i, AppendTo[equations, \[Rho][i, j][0] == 0]; j++]];
equations

Then I run the code
T = 20;
solutions = 
  NDSolve[equations, {\[Rho][1, 1], \[Rho][2, 1], \[Rho][2, 
     2], \[Rho][3, 1], \[Rho][3, 2], \[Rho][3, 3], \[Rho][4, 
     1], \[Rho][4, 2], \[Rho][4, 3], \[Rho][4, 4], \[Rho][5, 
     1], \[Rho][5, 2], \[Rho][5, 3], \[Rho][5, 4], \[Rho][5, 
     5], \[Rho][6, 1], \[Rho][6, 2], \[Rho][6, 3], \[Rho][6, 
     4], \[Rho][6, 5], \[Rho][6, 6]}, {t, 0, T}];

Which produces the error
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
I am not sure whether the source of the problem is that such a system is too large for NDSolve or if there's something wrong in the equations.
Notes:

I used Quiet[...] because in the code producing the equations some iterations evaluate a "physically wrong" ClebshGordan coefficient, however this is not a problem as Mathematica automatically sets them at 0, as I should expect for those coefficients.

I know that a lot of coefficients appear to be 0. I explicitly included them to have the code ready for a more general equation system I want to implement in the future. However, I expected Mathematica to automatically omit the terms with 0 coefficents. I tried to add also a "FullSimplify" in front of every equation in the iteration, but it didn't help much.



Evaluate equations at the initial condition and see what you get. If you solve for the derivatives of rho, you'll probably get something other than numbers.

I get mostly 0=0 identities, the only non-zero derivative is equal to Quantity[(0. - 5.9271*10^7 I), "Hertz"]. Could the fact that it bears dimensions be the issue?

It is unclear what equations you are trying to solve. Can you give a short explanation of your model? It is also unclear for what purpose you use dimensional values like "Kilohertz", "Amperes" "Meters")/("Hertz"). :)

The equation is the Lindbladian master equation for atomic hyperfine transitions. As for the dimensional values, I initially included them because I wanted to import physical constants in the code and they can be defined with Quantity[...], which gives dimensions to the variable. In any case after the calculation of all the parameters I added a QuantityMagnitude[...] to extract the pure numerical value and the issue was solved!
